# Loading an R shiny app but running into issues loading libraries

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shinyjs

My shiny app utilizes the `randomForestSRC` library. It operates fine on my own PC and in my version of R, but I am trying to upload it to an online server space where I need to manually install my apps. When I try to load this library, I get the following error message:

```
su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.
Warning: package â€˜randomForestSRCâ€™ was built under R version 4.3.1
Error: package or namespace load failed for â€˜randomForestSRCâ€™ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace â€˜htmltoolsâ€™ 0.5.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
Execution halted
```

So it appears that my `htmltools` library is loaded as an old version, which simply is not true. I have indeed installed the latest version of `htmltools`; there is no doubt about this.

What's notable is that when I try to load `htmltools` by itself, I then get THIS error message:

```
su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.
Warning: package â€˜htmltoolsâ€™ was built under R version 4.3.0
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Package â€˜htmltoolsâ€™ version 0.5.2 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace â€˜htmltoolsâ€™ is imported by â€˜shinyâ€™ so cannot be unloaded
Calls: runApp ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

In other words, it is telling me that some conflict with the shiny library is preventing it from loading the latest version of `htmltools`. This is confusing, because I have downloaded the latest version of `shiny`. It is worth noting that I don't even directly load the `shiny` library; I load `shinydashboard`, `shinyjs`, and `shinycssloaders`. I have also downloaded the latest versions of all of these libraries so I am really at a loss as to why I'm still running into old version issues. Lastly, when I run this on my computer, I load all these libraries without any conflicts between them.

I can't offer any code to reproduce this since I am using proprietary code on a proprietary server. This all works fine on my own computer anyway and thus would work fine on yours too.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: What's up with the `su:` warnings?

Comment: Whenever there are errors of the ilk `is already loaded ... is required`, the resolution is almost always *"restart all instances of R that are possibly using that package on that machine into a clean state with nothing loaded, then install/update that package, then try your first package again"*. In this case, stop all R (since R can "lock" a DLL when running, preventing upgrades), restart one R into a clean environment and `install.packages("htmltools")`. After that, try your randomForwardSRC installation.